# Change documentroot according to sub URI

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Assuming i have the following project structure

```
Root
- Frontend
-- index.php
- Backend
-- index.php
```

I want my www.mysite.com to use /www/root/frontend as the document root while /www/root/backend to be the document root if www.mysite.com/admin was requested. 
Note: Alias does exact match with /admin/ while i need /admin/* to work for the second case.

How should i go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache virtualhost config

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/root/backend/$1 [L]
```

So in context

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com

  DocumentRoot /www/root/frontend

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^admin [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/root/backend/$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```